# Url pr0blem, unable to retrieve ?tema=79 after page loads in address bar

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, url

http://fb.9nty.com/?t=Outrage+ShopRite&l=www.learnmoreng.com/forum2_theme_111582910.xhtml?tema=79

I use a Facebook share plugin to share links, but after links is shared and been click upon, the browser opens the page ignoring ?tema=79

Is there any ways to help?

I would want to use this: http://fb.9nty.com/?t=Outrage+ShopRite&l=www.learnmoreng.com/forum2_theme_111582910.xhtml&tema=79 
And implementing a code that automatically changes &tema  to ?tema and reloads the page

Comment: That's not how parameters in URL's work...To add parameters, you must have a ? then the parameters after it. & is only for multiple parameters, e.g. `tema=79&something=value`

Answer (score 1):

url encode the link (the part after &l=) - so the share link becomes:

http://fb.9nty.com/?t=Outrage+ShopRite&l=www.learnmoreng.com%2Fforum2_theme_111582910.xhtml%3Ftema%3D79